# Amazon Elastic Transcoder error 3003 Does Not Have Read Permission to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I am having trouble getting access to my input S3 bucket for my Amazon Elastic Transcoder pipeline.

`3003   Does Not Have Read Permission   The IAM role specified in the Role object in the pipeline that you used for this job doesn't have permission to read from the Amazon S3 bucket that contains the file you want to transcode.`

`3003 d6a37de0-6404-4cde-9c37-7aada57d54b2: You do not have the permissions required to read the specified object from the specified bucket: bucket=mybucket, key=myinputfile.MOV.`

- The bucket `mybucket` does not have a bucket policy
- the AIM role also has both `AmazonS3FullAccess` and `AmazonElasticTranscoderFullAccess` 
  Managed Policies

here is the custom inline policy for the IAM role that is attached to the Pipeline (Amazon Elastic Transcoder Pipeline):

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:*MultipartUpload*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "3",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Policy*",
                "sns:*Permission*",
                "sns:*Delete*",
                "s3:*Delete*",
                "sns:*Remove*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "4",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

If somebody could point me in the right direction and shed some light on how to grant my Amazon Elastic Transcoder access to my S3 bucket I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Did you by any chance solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late to reply to your question. I also got the same error today and found that the error was thrown due to presence of file with same name in the output bucket. Solution is to generate a different name or to delete your previous output files. I don't know why aws throws Permission errors.